# Javascript/Typescript: Can you look up number values in a list and replace them with strings?

Tags: javascript, list, typescript, dictionary

I have a list of integers [1,3,5] which I want to replace by text. Is there an elegant way to look up the values in a dictionary like in python? 
E.g.: 1 = Apple, 3 = Samsung, 5 = Nokia

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const dictionary = {1: "Apple", 3: "Samsung", 5: "Nokia"}

const result = [1,3,5].map(number => dictionary[number])
```

if the last line is cryptic to you, here is more old-fashioned way to write it:

```
const result = [1,3,5].map((number) => {return dictionary[number]})
```

Comment: Simply perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JavaScript Array where Answer[1] = "Apple";

Answer (score 1):

You can creat an object where the key will be 1,2,3 and there value will be apple

```js
let dictObj = {
  1: 'Apple',
  3: 'samsung',
  5: 'nokia'
}

let intList = [1, 3, 5];

intList.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(dictObj[item])
})
```